# How to deploy a .war to Tomcat7 without automatically starting it

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, jenkins

We've got a custom application that we are deploying to Tomcat7 using Jenkins.  The application requires properties files within the war containing configuration options (servers, database passwords, etc) that change depending on what environment we deploy it to. To make these changes we are currently using this procedure:

- Deploy .war file from nexus server to tomcat server using jenkins (act of deploying unpacks war and starts app, the app will throw errors because config in default properties files are incorrect).
- We then look for properties file inside the webapps/MyApp dir of tomcat, perform the appropriate search/replace transforms on the files to give correct config.
- We then issue a restart to the app to re-read the correct config in properties file.

This process is very ugly but we're not sure how else to do it.  We're stuck with these requirements:

- The developers would prefer not to rely on properties files outside of the war/webapps dir (or via JDNI) context for configuration and they don't want separate versions of the app in Nexus/SCM, each with a different config.  They only want one place in SCM from which to handle these files.
- We cannot store passwords in SCM and must rely on our deployment tool to do transforms on properties files.

We have tried editing the server.xml of tomcat7 and set autoDeploy="false", but even with this set, when we deploy the app, the app still starts up automatically after deploy.

What we want is a way to deploy the app to tomcat but NOT autostart such that we can do the edits on the parameters and then manually send a startup command to the app.  We cannot shut down all of tomcat as there are multiple other apps running on this tomcat instance.  We would also like for the app to still autostart on startup of tomcat (in case of unintended reboot), we just don't want it to autostart immediately after deploy.

Is this possible?  Are there other better ways of handling properties files that have variable configs?

Comment: is there some reason developers don't like properties outside the war? That's the best practice on doing this. .wars should not be environment specific. Another option is to use environment variables, not properties, but that would be outside .wars as well.

Comment: I agree with @eis, leave the configuration outside: use XML Context file to define where/what your configuration is. And in your app, handle (in a user friendly manner) when conf is missing or contains error.